# Control access to folders asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to deny access to my admin folder which is off root but it is saying that its inlvalid element. Yet I am using it within my web.config I dont want to post it in its entirity.

What I need is the ability to force login to the backdoor folder and anything that is in root allow annoymous access.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">

  <forms loginUrl="~/BackDoor/Login.aspx">


  </forms>
  <location path="~/BackDoor/">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</authentication>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`location`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.100).aspx) element must be defined outside of `system.web`:

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <-- loginUrl should be a page that anonymous users can access -->
      <forms loginUrl="~/BackDoorLogin.aspx">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>

  <location path="~/BackDoor/">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi i am getitng the following with this now 
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
when trying to access the login.aspx page on that folder

Comment: Looks like that will deny access to your login page since it is located under ~/BackDoor/. You could change the `loginUrl` to something like `~/BackDoorLogin.aspx`.

Comment: no i cant as the login is in the admin folder wanting to keep the folder secure but allow access to that url

Comment: Well, you can't secure your login page if you want people to be able to log in :)